# Flask deployment

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-platform, gunicorn

I've created a shopping site with a backend and a frontend.
The backend is python (3.6.5) with Flask.
I want to deploy my site to Google App Engine (gae).
When in development, everything works fine.
**When deployed (in production) each rpc gets it's own 'thread' and everything is a mess.**
I tried slapping gunicorn on it with sync and gevent worker class, but to no avail.

In deployment, how can I make each connection/session remember it's own 'instance of the backend'? 
-instead of gae/flask/gunicorn serving a new instance of the backend for each request?
I need each user connection to be consistent and 'its own'/'private'.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do this. App Engine will spread the request load to your application across all instances, regardless of which one previously handled a request from a specific IP. A specific instance may also come online or go offline due to load or underlying changes to App Engine (e.g., a data center needs maintenance).

If you need to maintain session state between multiple requests to your app, you have a couple options depending on the architecture:

- Keep session state in cookies with [`Flask.session`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#sessions)
- Keep session state in storage with [Memorystore](https://cloud.google.com/memorystore/)

Comment: I did not know that it was Google App Engine that caused the problem, but it seems you are right.
I'm not sure either of those options are viable for me...